# Spring Data JPA PageRequest order by Map value property

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Simplified version of my problem: Suppose there are two entities, Fish and Chip.

Fish has a one-to-many relation to Chip modeled as a Map:

```
public class Fish {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "the_map",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fish_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chip_id")
    )
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "the_key")
    private Map<Integer, Chip> chipsMap;
}
```

The following HQL-Query produces valid SQL:

```
from Fish order by chipsMap[2].createDate
```

Trying the same with Spring Data

```
PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(0, 10, 
    Sort.Direction.ASC.fromString("chipsMap[2].createDate"));

fishRepository.findAll(pr);
```

throws

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException:
    No property chipsMap[2] found for type Fish!
```

Problem in Spring Data JPA? Or wrong syntax?

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting), `Sort` needs a safe expression as it could potentially use unexposed properties and thus become a security problem. See [this CVE](https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2016-6652) for details.

If you know what you're doing and not using potentially malicious end user sort phrases, you can use `JpaSort.unsafe(…)`.

Comment: Hm, I've tried
`PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(0, 10, JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.ASC, "chipsMap[2].createDate"));`
and
`PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(0, 10, JpaSort.unsafe( "chipsMap[2].createDate"));`
- but both throw the same exception (No property chipsMap[2] found for type Fish!).

Comment: Moreover, `chipsMap[2].createDate` is a "referenceable path expression", so it should be not "unsafe", I think.